# Setting a margin based on a variable added to a number

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm trying to have the margin-bottom of an element being altered to the height of the next() element plus 12px. I tried the following, but this doesn't work.

```
$("div.entry-content").css("margin-bottom", $(this).next().outerHeight() + 12 + "px");
```

Any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.entry-content").css("margin-bottom", function(){
    return $(this).next().outerHeight() + 12 + "px"
})
```

Comment: @snuffn Yes, I had forgotten to write the return.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Do you mind explaining why a function is needed?

Comment: @BramVanroy Because `this` in your code doesn't refer to your desired element, `this` in the context of the function refers to the selected element, you can read about that in http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will read it through when I have sufficient time. I bumped into a similar problem. If you have time, please look into it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123267/setting-width-of-multiple-elements-with-same-class-depending-on-their-number