# Setting width of multiple elements with same class depending on their number

Tags: jquery, css, console, width

I'm experiencing a problem similar with one I had before. I'm trying to give multiple elements a width depending on how many of them exist.

Say I have 5 elements, their widths have to be 20%, if I have 4 25% etc. (width = 100 / n)

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
    if ($(window).width() <= 960) {

        $("aside.widget").css("width", function(){
            var widgetLength = $("section#secondary").children("aside.widget").length();
            return 100 / widgetLength + "%"
        });
    }
```

Nor does:

```
    if ($(window).width() <= 960) {         
        $("aside.widget").css("width", 100 / widgetLength + "%");
    }
```

Console returns: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should both work just fine, but length is **not** a function, so you need to change this:

```
var widgetLength = $("section#secondary").children("aside.widget").length();
```

to this:

```
var widgetLength = $("section#secondary").children("aside.widget").length;
```

then both the methods in your question will work!

Comment: Haha, that seems logical! Stupid mistake I suppose. Thanks!